# What are the different types of take-off minima at the bottom of a Jeppesen airport diagram?

Tags: takeoff, aeronautical-charts, jeppesen

> [image: LVTO procedures.]

Anyone that could explain the bottom plate, what’s the difference between all those minima?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The used acronyms are defined in the [Jeppesen charts legend](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf):

> **CL** Centerline Lights
> **RCLM** Runway Center Line Markings
> **RL** Runway (edge) Lights
> **RVR** Runway Visual Range

The first column tells us that a takeoff is authorized with RVR in touchdown zone (TDZ), midfield (MID) and rollout (RO) of at least 150m, **if** the RL and CL are operational (except during snow, where 400m is required, and for runway 18, where 250m is required).

The second column tells us that takeoff is authorized, if the RVR is at least 200m with RL and CL operational. In this case not all RVR values need to be available (e.g. one of them could be inop).

The third column tells us that takeoff is authorized, if the RVR is at least 300m and RL and RCLM are available (CL is not required, except at night).

The fourth column tells us that takeoff is authorized, if the visibility is at least 400m and either RL or RCLM (day) / RL or CL (night) are available.

The fifth column allows taking off with adequate visual reference during the day with at least 500m visibility. The "adequate vis ref" is defined in the charts legend as:

> ADEQUATE VIS REF (Adequate Visual Reference) — Runway markings or runway lighting that provides the pilot with adequate visual reference to continuously identify the take-off surface and maintain directional control throughout the take-off run.